Determine Google Cloud Logs size in bytes generated from Cloud Run services
I have over 30 cloud run services and I want to know which services generates the most logs in bytes in order to reduce logging costs.
I searched in the sample library of the Monitoring > Dashboards but couldnt find except these:

After doing a query for a service only
use this download functoriality to check size

